# connect to a webservice from android using KSoap

Tags: android, web-services

I am new to android. I need to connect to a webservice from android. The webservice method returns a string value bigger tham 10MB. I thought about trying to use KSOAP. Can someone give me a short example of connecting to a SOAP webservice  using KSOAP from android?

Comment: ahaaaa what did you google then? there are many examples already available.

Comment: I would recommend you to use `Json` for this. Its lightweight, easy and fast.

Comment: i need a simple application that read a file bigger tan 10MB and plays with it. is it possible? (load a file in it's memory, play with it and return it)

Comment: my webservice is SOAP. I can't use Json

Answer (score 1):

Add KSOAP jar file and use Async method for webservice

```
  public class Connection extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
 String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.example.com/Get/GetCount"; 
 String METHOD_NAME =   "GetCount"; 
 String NAMESPACE = "http://www.example.com";
 String URL = "http://www.example.com/Get.php?wsdl"; 
 String Result;
 SoapObject request1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME );
 request1.addProperty("AppId", 1); 
 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new soapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
 envelope.dotNet = true; envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request1);

 HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
 androidHttpTransport.debug = true; try {
 //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
 androidHttpTransport.call(soapaction, envelope);                           
 }  
 catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); } 
 catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
 { e.printStackTrace(); }
  // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.   
  SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;   
  Result = result.getProperty(0).toString();    
  JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject(Result);       
  JSONArray  Count = jArray.getJSONArray("Details");

 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 for(int i=0;i < Count .length();i++){                      

 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 JSONObject e = Count .getJSONObject(i);            
  map.put("id", e.getString("ID")); 
  myList.add(map);
 }
```

}